# Getting least squares calculations from QR decomposition

Tags: r, regression, qr-decomposition

I am a recent enthusiast into linear modelling and working on a function in R that implements common calculations from `lm` in R, to better understand how it works.

Essentially, with $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ we know that
$$(X^TX)^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\sum_{x_i^2}}{nS_{xx}}&-\frac{\bar{x}}{S_{xx}} \\ -\frac{\bar{x}}{S_{xx}} & \frac{1}{S_{xx}} \end{pmatrix}$$

How can I get this form with QR decomposition? After reading into 1/4 of Faraways linear models, he mentions at some point that QR decomposition is the way to go. How would I achieve the results from the above matrix form with QR decomposition?

So using a simple data:

```
x <- model.matrix( ~ Area + Elevation + Nearest + Scruz + Adjacent,
gala)

qrx <- qr(x)

(f <- t(qr.Q(qrx)) %*% y)

backsolve(qr.R(qrx),f)
```

This is what Faraway uses, does $f$ hold the results as above if we only have `t(qr.Q(qrx))`?

Comment: The formula you give for $(X^TX)^{-1}$ is not generallly true --- your formula only applies in a simple special case. The point of the QR decomposition is to compute the Cholesky factor of $X^TX$ without having to compute $X^TX$ and to compute $\hat\beta$ without having to invert any matrices.